# append formData not working in IE11

Tags: jquery, ajax, form-data

I am using Ajax to send a file using formData appending items with the file. It works in every browser except IE 11 and I can't figure out why.

```
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('firstId', firstId);
        formData.append('secondId', secondId);
        formData.append('mainDoc', $('#file').prop('files')[0]);
```

On the backend its using HttpPostedFileBase. I also have

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) says appending files with a filename isn't supported in IE, but not quite sure if that's true?

Comment: Yeah I tried the generic 'file' as well, no luck

Comment: @Keith did you find a way to solve this ?

Comment: Yes, using formData.append('mainDoc', $('#file')[0].prop('files')[0];